# Wordpress search field won't get wider

Tags: theme-development, css

I've tried everything I know how to get this input field to 100% but I can't seem to do it. It always stays at some stuck width. `.search-field` is the stock class and I've targeted that class using `max-width: none;` or `width: 100%;` and or `input {width: 100%;}` but it never changes. Has anyone else experienced this? If so, what was your solution, if any?

Comment: Have you used the Inspector to see the generated code? Perhaps there is a hardcoded style in that field. Use the inspector to also see the CSS class assigned to that element. Then you can use the appropriate CSS class name to override the value. The Inspector is also good to try out various CSS tags on an element; you can see immediate effect.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, actually. It's just so strange! I just wonder if wordpress embeds a style... maybe even the function that overrides what can be changed in CSS. I've tried to really drill down -> `div.search input#search-input.search-field`. I could change font-family, padding and everything else, basically, but just not the width!

Comment: Inspector can help you see if there is an embedded style. Or looking at the source code. Could be the theme that is fixing the length. Could be in header.php or sidebar.php (if a widget).

Comment: I posted this on wordpress.org and someone noticed that pixels work but percentages don't. I'm not marking this as solved just yet as I'm holding on to hope that someone can figure out how to make percentages work :)

Comment: Percentages are based on the parent container size. Pixels will override the parent container size, if the number of pixels is wider than the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Over on wordpress.org, A user commented that targeting this path:

`header form.search-form, header .search input { width: 100%; }` might work and it did.

I didn't realize that targeting the form would have transpired to much but it did. His answer resolved it.